# C# Regex.Replace - search for matches in replacement string as well

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following:

```
string input = "xSxSx";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, "xSx", "xTx");
// result == "xTxSx"
```

It looks like the replacement string is not used for further matching, which is why we don't get the expected "xTxTx".

How to solve that? Is there some kind of special notation to tell the engine to find for a second match using the string with the first replacement already in place?

Comment: You probably wouldn't want that to be default behavior, because then `Regex.Replace(input, "a", "aa")` would produce an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because, once a character is matched, it won't be matched again. So, 2nd time the string to match is `Sx` and not `xSx`.

You would need to use *look-arounds* here:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=x)S(?=x)", "T");
```

This will replace the `S` which is both *preceded* and *succeeded* by `x` with a `T`. Since *look-arounds* are *0-length* assertion, they will not consume `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop for anything more complex that you can't simplify into a look[ahead/behind].

```
    string test = "xSxSx";
    string result = string.Empty;
    while(true) {
        result = Regex.Replace(test, "xSx", "xTx");
        if(result != test) 
            test = result;
        else 
            break;
    }
```